# Does using auto makes the site slower?

Tags: css

I am planning to use some `auto` in my css. However, I was wondering if using that `auto` keyword instead of explicitly declaring pixels make the site download or display slower by any means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using the auto keyword in css does not generally have an impact on the performance of a website.

It is generally more important to consider the overall size and number of resources (such as images and fonts) on your website, as well as the efficiency of your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code, when optimizing the performance of your website.